# Reformatting slashes in string

Tags: c#, string, escaping

i am trying to reformat a string value. i have

> "\"\/Date(1430370000000+0530)\/\""

this i need to reformat to , I want the string to be like below:

> "/Date(1430370000000-0530)/"

I tried writting following c# code , but gives error

```
string str =  "\"\\/Date(1430370000000+0530)\\/\"";                                 

str = str.Replace(""\\"," ");

Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Could you please help?

Comment: Sure, it will produce an error as `""\\"` is not a correctly formed string literal. What are the requirements?

Comment: If you would store your string in a file, what would be the value, this: `"\"\/Date(1430370000000+0530)\/\""`? Or is that the string literal that you have used to initialize the string? It's not clear what original string you have and what the expected result is. It's not even clear what rules for the replacement you have. You basically ask: i have string `a` and i want string `b`, how do i get it?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Maybe [`str.Replace("\"\\", "\"").Replace("\\/\"", "/\"")`](https://ideone.com/wDYctk)? Note that currently, your original *literal* string is `"\/Date(1430370000000+0530)\/"`. Do you need the `"/Date(1430370000000+0530)/"` as the literal string output?

Comment: i need this  "/Date(1475038800000-0500 )/ "

Comment: above str.repace not working

Comment: @SmartestVEGA Isn't `"/Date(1430370000000+0530)/"` the expected one? do you mean there must be a space before `)`? See https://ideone.com/Tr8iEp

Comment: expected this "\/Date(1430370000000-0530)\/"

Comment: No spaces are required

Comment: You have different numbers in the original string and the result.

Comment: corrected now in the question

Comment: Please provide the strings as **literal strings** and use the 4-space indentation to show code in the question. Also, check [this demo](https://ideone.com/Tr8iEp). If the literal string is `"\/Date(1430370000000+0530)\/"`, the output literal string is `"/Date(1430370000000+0530)/"` (just ``\`` are removed)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how exactly you want the stuff to be replaced. Could you give more examples or a set of rules please.

Anyway at least something like this compiles

```
        string str = "\"\\/Date(1430370000000+0530)\\/\"";

        str = str.Replace("\"\\"," ");
        Console.WriteLine(str);
```

The reason it didn't compile earlier is because the `""` ends the string, so `\\` is outside the string. \" is taken as a character.

An alternative approach to the problem which might be simpler is as follows.

```
            string str = "\"\\/Date(1430370000000+0530)\\/\"";
            int pFrom = str.IndexOf("Date");
            int pTo = str.LastIndexOf(")");

            String result = str.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom+1);
            result= "\\/"+result+"\\/";
```

Comment: I m expecting "\/Date(1475038800000-0500)\/" but got  /Date(1430370000000+0530)\/"

Comment: What do you actually want to do exactly? If you explain, I could write something up

Comment: i need to get "\/Date(1430370000000-0530)\/" output